# Generics: Cannot cast to multiple generic type

Tags: java, generics, casting

Following structure

```
abstract class EntityClazz<ENTITY>{}

abstract class DTOClazz<DTO extends DTOClazz<DTO>> {}

interface Fee<SOME extends DTOClazz>{}

public class FuuDTO extends DTOClazz<FuuDTO>{}

public class FuuEntity extends EntityClazz<FuuEntity> implements Fee<FuuDTO>{
    static List<FuuEntity> findBySomeData(String someData){ ...}
}

public class FiiDA<DTO extends DTOClazz<DTO>, ENTITY extends EntityClazz<ENTITY> & Fee<DTO>> {
    public void findBySomething(String data) {
    //This does not work!
        List<ENTITY> findSomeThing = (List<ENTITY>)FuuEntity.findBySomeData(data);
    }
}
```

## EDIT 1

Added more classes/impl:

```
void someTest() {
    FiiDA<FuuDTO, FuuEntity> da = new FiiDA(); 
    da.findBySomething("HELLO WORLD");
}
```

Yeah please do not tell me that this is crap. I do know this by myself!

The cast is just considered as unchecked cast and I do not get it because the compiler says:

> cannot be converted to java.util.List< ENTITY >

I don't get it. Is this type erasure?? But the FuuEntity does implement the interface and the EntityClazz. Why can't I just cast it. It should not matte what really is inside.

Comment: Please provide all the classes so I can compile this my side.

Comment: You have several issues. for example, you call `FuuEntity.findBySomeData` as if it was a static method, but it's not. You also use a raw type - `DTOClazz`.

Comment: Thanks I forgot to add this :D

Comment: Your updated code passes compilation for me (after adding a return statement to the static method). What's the exact problem you have? A warning? An error?

Comment: I am currently compiling these lines of code with Java 8 and in Intellij it's just considered as an "unchecked cast". But at compile time it throws me an compile error with: 'cannot be converted to java.util.List<ENTITY>'

Answer (score 0):

List of subclass can't be casted to list of the superclass. Example: `List<Dog>` list can't be casted to `List<Animal>`, the reason behind this is you might end up adding a Cat to the list that was supposed to have only Dogs.

```
List<Parent> myList = new ArrayList<Child>();//Won't work
```

> There's a very simple rule here—the type of the variable declaration
>   must match the type you pass to the actual object type. If you declare
>   List foo, then whatever you assign to the foo reference MUST be
>   of the generic type . Not a subtype of . Not a supertype of
>   . Just `<Foo>`

Comment: Isn't this what the unchecked is saying.

Comment: Yes, the reason why that cast is not allowed in Java is explained above. Let me know if you want me to show it thru an example.

Comment: Okay .... I tested several things in a new project know. I generally need just the interface 'Fee' what should I do then. Is there any possibility to add these. And I am confused because in Java 7 it worked.